# How to tell haskell stack to use an installed package?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I've been able to use the `Data.Tuple.Extra` module after installing the `extra` package by `stack build extra`.  But the same doesn't apply to the `Data.List.Unique` module (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Unique-0.4.7.8/docs/Data-List-Unique.html).  According to the website, it's included in package `Unique`.  So, I installed it with

```
$ stack build Unique
```

The installation seems to have been successful because I didn't see any error messages.  But

```
$ cat try.hs
import Data.List.Unique
main = do putStrLn "hello"
$ stack runghc try.hs

try.hs:1:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Data.List.Unique’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
1 | import Data.List.Unique
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
$
```

The output from `stack runghc -v try.hs` is too big for me to analyze . . .

**Note:** I've modified the question to focus on the installation and use of modules.  Following the answers provided below, I'm able to run the program using an option.  Still, it would be nice if one wouldn't need to use a package option.

Comment: On your edit: If you set up a project for your code, you can specify `Unique` as a dependency of it only once, in the project configuration file, as opposed to every time you want to run it.

Comment: @duplode  I see.  All my programs are small and stand-alone, not worthy of the name "project". Writing dependencies for each little program is overkill. That probably means that I should add packages to `.stack/global-project/stack.yaml`. Then I'm stuck.  Do you know which document should I look at?  A simple "packages:\n - Unique" doesn't work --- stack tries to find a directory named "Unique".

Comment: For small programs I don't feel like setting up a proper project for, what I usually do is putting them all into a "playground" directory, in which I have a project set up only for the purpose of specifying the dependencies. The alternative is specifying the dependencies in each file, using the Stack script format suggested in Fyodor Soikin's answer. (As for the global project, it operates on a different level: it is used to specify defaults for where Stack will fetch dependencies from, but not for which dependencies will be available in your code.)

Answer (score 2):

`stack build` doesn't "install" the package globally for use with every compilation, and `runghc` can't pick up Stack packages. It's meant to be a more or less direct execution of GHC.

You can specify packages to use if you run your program with `stack try.hs`, as described in [the docs](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#script-interpreter). In that case, you'll be able to specify packages to use with specially formatted comments, like this:

```
-- stack script --package Unique
import Data.List.Unique
main = do putStrLn "hello"
```

Comment: While `runghc` can't pick up Stack packages, `stack runghc` can, also by using the `--package` option.

Comment: Well, good to know. I couldn't find any docs on the subject (Stack docs just say "it runs runghc"), so I thought I'd go with a safer, more stable option.

Answer (score 2):

The *Unique* dependency can be specified by passing the `--package` option to `runghc`:

```
stack runghc --package Unique try.hs
```

Alternatively, you can make `try.hs` a [Stack script](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#script-interpreter), as illustrated by [Fyodor Soikin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66602281/2751851).

If you plan to develop `try.hs` into more than a standalone file, consider setting up a Stack project. See the [Hello World example](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#hello-world-example) in the Stack User Guide for initial guidance on that.

Comment: Thanks!  But, I wonder why I don't need the `--package` option for `Data.Sort`.  I did need to install the `sort` package with `stack build sort`.

Comment: @Ryo That's pretty odd. In any case, it is generally not necessary to explicitly install libraries with e.g. `stack build`. You just have to tell Stack you need the library (in this case, through the `--package` option), and it will take care of making it available. `stack build` is primarily meant for building your projects, and not its dependencies.